# Yandex-карта как слой в Google Maps — возможно ли?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Возможно ли добавить в слой Google-карты карту Яндекса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openstreetmap вроде бы можно, а Яндекс кто его знает..

Answer (score 2):

Технически возможно, но у них по моему проекции разные, поэтому они один в один не лягут, а в некоторых местах будут большие расхождения.

Comment: один в один не лягут это точно